# Is the set $X = \{(x, y, z) ∈ \Bbb R^3: y = 1\}$ a subspace of $ \Bbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra and math in general. I understand that you need the zero vector  to be in set $X$, you need it closed under vector addition and vector multiplication. Is this closure for the set $X$ itself or in the general vector space.

For instance if I take two arbitrary vectors $(a_1, 1, a_3) \in X$ and $(a_4, 1, a_6)\in X$, then their sum is not in $S$ itself (since second entry would be 2)  but is in $\Bbb R^3$. Does this satisfy closure property of addition or is a counter example?

How is the zero vector property here coming in play?

Comment: Is the zero vector in $X$? – You also demonstrated that $X$ is *not* closed under addition.

Comment: You are right, your counterexample proves that $X$ is not a subspace.

Comment: This set $X$ does not obey all of the three requirements of subspace..!

Comment: I see so two arbitrary vectors have to be closed under addition and multiplication and be elements of the set itself, not just the general space! What is the point of checking for the zero vector?

Comment: Yeah so you check for any two arbitrary vectors in set X is their sum also in X. For any arbitrary vector in X and some arbitrary real number , is their product also in X. You check for zero vector to ensure non-emptiness.

Comment: Requiring that the sum of two vectors $a, b \in X$ is an element of $\Bbb R^3$ would be rather pointless, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument correctly shows $X$ is not a subspace.
You state three conditions for $X$ to be a subspace.  If any one of the three fails, you can stop, and conclude it is not a subspace.  (In fact, in this example all three conditions fail.)

Answer (score 0):

As is pointed out on the comments, you need to check for the zero vector to guarantee nonemptiness. If you already know your set is not empty, then you can skip this verification and use the fact that $v-v = 0$ together with the other two closure properties to get that zero is a member of your subspace.

Note that you can check for nonemptiness by any other means, but usually just checking for the zero vector is the easiest/quickest way. Furthermore, also note there is only one empty set, so the only way you could find a "subspace" that satisfies the two closure properties but has no zero vector would be by finding some properties which are preserved under addition and scalar multiplication but which are never satisfied by any vector.

An example of this cleverly disguised empty set can be found in [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315831/787310)